# Distinguish between f() and f(**kwargs) in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'd like to be able to tell if a function was declared as `f()` or `f(**kwargs)` in Python 2.7, so I know whether or not it can accept arbitrary keyword arguments... but invoke.getargspec.args() returns [] in both cases.  Is there a way of doing this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to look at `inspect.getargspec().keywords` instead. If it is `None` no `**kwargs` was given.

From the [`inspect.getargspec()` documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#inspect.getargspec):

> *varargs* and *keywords* are the names of the `*` and `**` arguments or `None`.

Demo:

```
>>> import inspect
>>> def foo(): pass
... 
>>> def bar(**kwargs): pass
... 
>>> inspect.getargspec(foo).keywords is None
True
>>> inspect.getargspec(bar).keywords is None
False
>>> inspect.getargspec(bar).keywords
'kwargs'
```